# How to resolve systemd reports "Starting Download data for packages that failed at package install time"

Tags: apt, package-management

I get this every day (once per day) since dist-upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04.

```
2022-10-25T12:04:46.267623+00:00 redacted systemd[1]: Starting Download data for packages that failed at package install time...
2022-10-25T12:04:46.421005+00:00 redacted systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.service: Deactivated successfully.
2022-10-25T12:04:46.422034+00:00 redacted systemd[1]: Finished Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
```

`apt-get check` reports no problems. I just did an `apt-get update` to see if that fixes it for tomorrow.

Is there a service that runs daily that performs Apt work?

**Is there a way to figure out exactly what package(s) it's stuck on?**

I prefer not to just `apt-get upgrade` everything if possible. This system is a production system with change-restrictions. Currently there's a window a week out where I can do an upgrade…

**apt-get upgrade has not resolved this**

I've since had a chance to `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` to no avail.

Comment: Now do an apt-get upgrade to apply the packages.

Comment: …I don't want to upgrade anything I don't have to. This system is under change-restrictions. I can make a case for upgrading whatever it is that it's complaining about (in those logs)… my actual question is how do I figure out what exactly it's stuck on?

Comment: You need to add this info to the question that you do not want upgrades.

Comment: done (10charstog

Comment: I've now had a chance to do the full `apt-get update` and an `apt-get upgrade` — these daily recurring errors persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a systemd "timer" unit which seems to belong to the update-notifier package. Except, that package is not actually installed on this sytem. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

I finally realized what was going on via, `systemctl status update-notifier-download.timer` and `systemctl status update-notifier-download.service`. `/lib/systemd/system/update-notifier-download.service` doesn't have an `[Install]` section, so simply stopping and disabling the timer does the trick…

```
# systemctl stop update-notifier-download.timer
# systemctl disable update-notifier-download.timer
```